# Getting the post ID outside outside of the Wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress

So I have a snippet of code that grabs the categories and their coinciding posts and lists them outside of the loop (Below). I've been trying to get the post to link to #post-[ID] instead of the permalink - but I keep failing. Can anyone help?

```
<ul id="sidebar">
<?php
    foreach( get_categories('orderby=ID&order=desc') as $cat ) :
    if( !$cat->parent ) {
    echo '<li class="title"><h2><a href="#">' . $cat->name . '</a></h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    process_cat_tree( $cat->term_id );
            }
    endforeach;

    wp_reset_query(); //to reset all trouble done to the original query
    //
    function process_cat_tree( $cat) {
    $args = array('category__in' => array( $cat ), 'numberposts' => -1);
    $cat_posts = get_posts( $args );
    $id = $post->ID;

    global $post;
    if( $cat_posts ) :
    foreach( $cat_posts as $menuPost ) :
    echo '<li';
    if ( $menuPost->ID == $post->ID ) { echo ' class="active"'; }
    echo '>';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $menuPost->ID ) . '">' . $menuPost->post_title . '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
    endforeach;
    endif;

    echo '</ul></li>';
    }
?>
```

The above code is outputting UL/LI tags like this:

- CATEGORY

  - Post
  - Post
  - Post
- CATEGORY

  - Post
  - Post
  - Post
- CATEGORY

  - Post
  - Post
  - Post

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean by "linking to #post-[ID]" and I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly, I don't exactly understand what you mean by "linking to #post-[ID]", but going with the question title:

If you use `get_permalink()` when echoing the link, you will get the permalink - that's just what that function does.

Use `get_the_ID()` instead, if you want the post-ID returned, or `the_ID()` if you want it displayed (`the_ID()` is the same as `echo get_the_ID()`).

**Edited from here:**

If you're otherwise happy with the above code, changing

```
 echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $menuPost->ID ) . '">' . $menuPost->post_title . '</a>';
```

to

```
 echo '<a href="#post-' . $menuPost->ID . '">' . $menuPost->post_title . '</a>';
```

ought to do it.

However, I'd go about it like so:

```
echo '<ul>';
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories = get_categories($cat_args);

foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<li class="title"><h2><a href="#">' . $category->name . '</a></h2><ul>';
    // query posts of that category:
    $query_args = array(
        'cat' => $category->cat_ID,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $your_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    // loop through them:
    while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
        echo '<li><a href="#post-';
        the_ID();
        echo '">';
        the_title();
        echo '</a></li>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</ul></li>';
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I will be implementing the Jquery Tabs. Since each post is assigned a post-[id], I need the link in the posts by category list to point to #post-[id].  And FYI: I'm somewhat new to Wordpress development.

Comment: @user1036169 Okay. Let's forget your code snippet above for a second - there's a load of weirdness going on in there. I for instance see a `wp_reset_query();` but not a `new WP_Query()` in the first place. You need a list of all posts ordered by (sub)category. In each list item you want what information exactly? Please update your question with a non-code example of list structure and list item content.

Comment: so I replaced
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $menuPost->ID ) . '">' . $menuPost->post_title . '</a>';

with
echo '<a href="#post-' . get_the_ID( $menuPost->ID ) . '">' . $menuPost->post_title . '</a>';

but it's outputting the same ID for every link. Any idea what's causing that?

Comment: It's outputting the ID of the post/page you're currently on. In order for it to do what you want, it has to be **within** [the Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). See my above comment - unfortunately, your code cannot be fixed by changing one line. I know your question title suggests that you want it outside, but you don't need to use the theme's in-built Loop. Still you need to loop through the posts correctly.

Comment: So to get it to work the way I need it to it NEEDS to be inside the Loop? But if I put it in the Loop the JQuery tabs won't work correctly will it? Forgive me if I'm a little confused.

Comment: @user1036169 Appended both a change in your code, as well as my take on accomplishing this.

Comment: @user1036169 Don't thank me too early - test the code in production. If it works, be so kind as to mark this question as solved / the answer as correct, respectively.

Comment: So far it's working locally, So I'm assuming it should work live.